# Negation of absent fact in prolog

Tags: prolog

let's say I have;

```
goal(A,B) :- goal1(A,C), \+ goal2(C,B).
```

but now let's say `goal(c,b)` cannot be inferred.

If I query, `\+ goal(c,b)` then I get true
but, if I query `goal(a,B)`, then I don't get `B=b`, because, it doesn't even check for `goal2(c,b)` (as it can't be inferred). It just checks all present facts `goal2(C,B)` and picks only those that are false.

Now that is the problem. I want to `B=b` as the answer when I query something like `goal(a,B)`. Is it possible in prolog. Note that I don't want to insert negative fact like `goal(c,b):-false` in prolog.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you try to get a working example? Like, provide example definitions for goal1/2 and goal2/2 as well as the queries you want to use.

Comment: Ok a simpler example @TA_intern : - We can have  a father/2 relation defined, few facts. Then I want to know all the persons whose father is not 'a'. So something like ?-notfather(a,X). Then i think the challenge is to define notfather/2. Because if i define notfather(A,B) :- \+father(A,B). same problem arises

Comment: Basically if there is a way prolog substitutes all constants defined in database into the negation rule to check, instead of using only existing inferred rules to check. Then it can work. I think now you know what is the problem.

Comment: Can't you write this in the question? It is really difficult to understand code that I cannot copy-paste and run on my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempting to guess from your question, say we have:

```
p(a, 1).
p(c, 2).
p(d, 1).
p(e, 2).
```

and you wanted to query all p/2 where the second argument is *not* 2, you can either do:

```
?- p(X, Y), Y \== 2.
```

or:

```
?- dif(Y, 2), p(X, Y).
```

Read the docs to see what is the difference. There are many a question here on SO that discuss this.

Comment: Hey, that seems to work for me:). Thanks. So the idea is if i want to check 'all constants' defined in database, they must be in some fact. Then I want use those facts to check for that constant.

Comment: @Tojrah I don't know. I really have trouble understanding without code examples :(